# How to implement Mantra MFS100 fingerprint sensor in a tkinter application?

Tags: python, tkinter, fingerprint

I have never developed such application which connects to a hardware, recently i got a challenge to build a desktop app in windows 10 for attendance purpose, For authentication I have got Mantra MFS100 fingerprint scanner which will be connected using its USB. But I cant see any library in python to read its signal, or how to handle functions. Do you guys have any solution to complete this job in `tkinter` ?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is less related to tkinter. Its more a question of how you get the data and what data you can get. There are options like the *usblib* or *pyserial*.

Comment: @Atlas435 do you know any reference where i can get it easily to implement on my project ?

Comment: seems like [someone did it in java](https://github.com/vekain/Mantra-MFS-100/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/mega2/final_livw_demo/MFS100_final.java). Also note *Programming Languages

MFS100 SDK supports Microsoft .Net, Java and Android languages. MFS100 SDK and RD Service can also be integrated in web-form based application such as .htm, .html, .asp, .aspx, .cshtml, .jsp, .php etc… via ajax CORS call on http and https based protocol.* [source](https://www.mantratec.com/Drivers-SDK)

Comment: @Atlas435 I also know that but i dont want to create server for that, and thinking not to use .net framework or java

Comment: How did you do it please? I have the same problem.

Comment: @Bubble installed the mfs100 sdk, they are providing the service over localhost server, I an communicating using request library